# How to generate uptime reports through Google Cloud Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am a new user with Google cloud (Stackdriver).

I would like to set and generate uptime reports on a monthly basis which would include the past 4 weeks through e-mail in the cloud but I have not been able to find from where I could do this.

I have done research but have not managed to find what I am looking for. The closes I got to was TRACE but is still not what I would like to have.

Comment: I assume you want a report saying that VM no.1 was up for 83% of time for the last 4 weeks and VM no.2 was up por 98% of time - am I correct or you want something else ?

Comment: I would like to report the platform uptime which accumulates in the dashboard within Google Cloud? does this make sense when I say this?

Comment: What do you mean by "accumulates" ? Do you want to see (instead of percentage uptime) a real time ? Like 453hrs of 720 (24h*30days) ?

Comment: I will try to explain this better, when you are in Google Cloud > Monitoring > Uptime Checks [In this section you can see in our case, uptime percentage graphs towards one of our platform] - one can choose a timeline of, [1 hour, 6 hours, 1 day, 1 week, 1 month or 6 weeks].  What I would like to do is that, instead of me going every month and extract this information manually, I generate this through a report from Google Cloud itself. So far I have not found this feature.

Comment: Additional information; Cloud does not retrain data in dashboards for more than 6 weeks so we need to manually extract the uptime data for each week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to generate that kind of reports using tools available in Google Cloud.

Using traces is probably the best you can do now - although you can try the [Cloud Trace API](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/reference) which may give you a way to extract the information in a more structured way.

If you want this feature included in GCP please go to [IssueTracker and create a new feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187228&template=1163027) with detailes explanation of what your goal is and mention the time-span you want to be able to get data from.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - if my answer helped you in any way I would be greatful if you accept it :)