# How to get the Uptime Percentage from Uptime check

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, uptime, uptime-monitoring, website-monitoring

[image: Uptime Percentage]

I want to fetch the Uptime percentage from the above image to a third party application I am making. I have gone through various documentation but couldn't find anything!

Can anyone guide me through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for now to generate such metric / graph to show uptime percentage of the VM's.

You may try to extract that information using [cloud trace API](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/reference).

Another approach may be to use MQL query to create a custom metric to show total uptime agregated by hours/days etc.

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime'
| filter (metric.instance_name == 'instance-1')
| align delta(1d)
| every 1d
| group_by [], [value_uptime_mean: mean(value.uptime)]
```

[image]

Additionally you may find those answers helpful:

[How to generate uptime reports through Google Cloud Stackdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441664/how-to-generate-uptime-reports-through-google-cloud-stackdriver)

[How to get uptime total and percentage of GCP compute vm instance through MQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079794/how-to-get-uptime-total-and-percentage-of-gcp-compute-vm-instance-through-mql)

[Get google cloud uptime history to a third party application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311747/get-google-cloud-uptime-history-to-a-third-party-application)